# Screen Keyboard on - how to activate it

Tags: onscreen-keyboard

With Screen Keyboard switched on, I wonder how I can activate it. Sometimes it appears as when logging in and while typing the password, but in many other situations it does not appear.

How can I make it appear when I need it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are in Ubuntu 17.04 or later, it should activate on its own whenever you click on an input field [read this](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-osk.html.en) for more info. For me it appears each time I touch the display on an input field.

*Hope this helps.*

Comment: With 18.04.4 LTS this does not work. For example now, while typing this, no keyboard appears.

Comment: Hmm, I'm on the same version but works properly for me.

Comment: Could it be your display?

Comment: How can I test this? Sometimes it appears. In terminals this seems to be always reproducible. But not in Firefox windows it seems.

Comment: Are you using a  touchscreen display?

Comment: No, regular laptop

Comment: have you tried both on `xorg` and `wayland`, is it the same behavior?

Comment: No. I do need X.

Comment: I am on `xorg` for the record, try installing `xorg` and test it out it that could be the issue

Comment: Thank you. I hoped for a simple solution which does not exist it seems.

Comment: Sometimes I hate on `linux` as well but kinda got used to it, keep trying `windows` but just makes things harder, gotta give a try to `Mac`, sorry for not being able to help you.